# Flutter project not auto-generating package name in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: flutter

Hey Stack Overflow community,

I recently created `a new Flutter project` using **Flutter version 3.16.7 (stable)** and `Dart version 3.2.4`. However, I noticed that the **package name is not automatically generated** in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I'm using `Android Studio version Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1.`

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="simple"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <!-- ... other configurations ... -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Is there something I might be missing, or is this a known issue with the versions I'm using? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Please check your package name in App's build.gradle, it shows as `namespcae`

```
|-android
|--app
|---build.gradle
```

`build.gradle`

```
android {
    namespace "com.app.yourpackagename" <-- Here.
    compileSdkVersion 33
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Gradle-based build system package name removed from manifest file and now package name in app/build.gradle is final for app uploading process (Play store).

[android developer guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjdrF.png)

You can find more detafrom here - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element

If you add android: package manuall in AndroidManifest.xml file still it will be override from app/build.gradle file.

[app/build.gradle file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGKXP.png)